# Lightning file upload

Tags: lightning-aura-components

While uploading an image in salesforce using tag lightning:fileUpload, we will be redirected to a pop up where we can upload an image. But while uploading, on click of cross mark next to progress bar, the image upload is not getting terminated. First, it will show "upload failed", post that the progress bar shows blue color, and next to it shows a green tick mark.

[image: green tick for cancelled upload]

Can anyone suggest how to resolve this issue.

Comment: I have been able to reproduce this behavior in my org based on https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:fileUpload/documentation . I have added image to your description. This does not seem to be working as designed. I will reach out to salesforce product team to confirm this is a bug. Thanks

Comment: I see that this behavior is due to the small file size, where it actually gets uploaded before the user can cancel. In case the image is of large size(or an image is uploaded on a slower internet connection), this does not seem to happen. Thanks

Comment: But is there any work around not to have this issue in all the times,whether it might be small or bigger image?

Comment: The component supports multi-file upload, and generally, if a user uploads multiple images/files, they would have time to cancel some of the later ones. This does seem to be a bug that the upload happens in the background faster than the UI can keep up. The workaround would be to delete the file after its uploaded if users weren't able to cancel in time.